# Simple manager for systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, init-script, sysvinit, runlevel

Is there a manager that would run in the console, similar to `sysv-rc-conf`, that works with the latest **systemd** under Linux?

Ideally it would be able to operate on all runlevels, and be ncurses based.

Comment: Runlevels is a sysv concept that doesn't exist in `systemd`, although `systemd` targets are similar.

Comment: `yast`'s `services-manager` module.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to prove non-existence, but all of the discussion which I find deals with the *absence* of anything analogous from `systemd`.  Perhaps someone will reinvent it in a few years after the mess remaining from incomplete migration from `chkconfig` is completed (`systemd` definitely needs a tool of that sort).

Further reading:

- [sysv-rc-conf: Going, going, gone](https://inconsolation.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/sysv-rc-conf-going-going-gone/)
- [rcconf-style tool for systemd?](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/34i5pb/rcconfstyle_tool_for_systemd/)
- [How Linux Boots, Run Levels, and Service Control](http://cromwell-intl.com/linux/linux-boot.html)
- [How do I install chkconfig on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680050/how-do-i-install-chkconfig-on-ubuntu)